# "Weak statements" about derivatives of $L^p$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a Lemma which states that under certain conditions
$$ div ~ q = 0 ~~~~~~~~(1)$$
for a periodic function $q \in (L_{loc}^p (\mathbb{R}^n))^n$. This should be meant in the weak sense:
$$ \int q \cdot \nabla \phi = 0 ~~~~~~~~(2)$$ 
for all test functions $\phi \in C_0^\infty$. [Source here (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2nHO.jpg)

However, my question is not about the assumptions, but the divergence. **Why do we talk about the divergence here?** $q$ does not have (weak) derivatives, so technically "$div~ q$" does not exist. It would make sense for e.g. a $q \in W^{1,p}$. Is this just notation for convenience? Or is it an actual statement about the existence of the partial derivatives of $q$? The paper continues to use (1), but not (2), which doesn't help to clear my confusion.

I know this question is vague, but any help is appreciated.

---

Background: I am a student in applied math and need to understand the paper for a seminar. My advisor is absent for 2-3 weeks, but I still want to continue :)

[This is a follow-up question to this (answered) question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506656/definition-of-the-lebesgue-space-lp-n) Sadly, I do not have a proof of the above Lemma, as it only refers to a thesis I cannot obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can look at it is at the sense of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Every function that is quite "reasonable" has a derivative in that sense, while it might be nowhere differentiable.

In your case, since we can talk about the distributional derivative of an $L^p_{{\rm loc}}$ function,  the assumption $\int q\nabla \phi=0$ for all $\phi\in C_0^{\infty}$ is equivalent to the distributional divergence being equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I never saw distributions in my courses, only in formulations like "... in the distributional sense". But I always assumed that "weak derivative/sense" and "distributional derivative/sense" were the same. I guess this is not the case, since every locally integrable function seems to have a distributional derivative (but not a weak one)? Or are there be special cases where these coincide?

Comment: You are right, this is not always the case; for example, the derivative of the Heaviside function $f(x)=\max\{x,0\}$ is equal to the Dirac $\delta$ at $0$, but this function is not weakly differentiable around $0$ in the Sobolev space sense.

Comment: @hank789: It is more or less along these lines: 1. every function in $L^1_{loc}$ is a distribution. 2. every distribution has a derivative, which is again a distribution. 3. if $f \in L^1_{loc}$ and its distributional derivative (as a distribution) can be represented by $g \in L^1_{loc}$, this $g$ is also the weak derivative. So if you merely work with functions in $L^1_{loc}$ you do not see the difference between weak and distributional derivative.